# Qt + KDE, управление воспроизведением через виджет

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11, kde

Есть приложение которое воспроизводит музыку через `QMediaPlayer`.
К плееру добавлен список тректов через `QMediaPlaylist`.

```
mediaPlayer = new QMediaPlayer;
playList = new QMediaPlaylist;

playList->addMedia(QUrl("http://localhost/track1.mp3"));
playList->addMedia(QUrl("http://localhost/track2.mp3"));
mediaPlayer->setPlaylist(playList);
playList->setCurrentIndex(0);
```

---

В KDE Plasma 5 есть виджет который позволяет управлять процессом воспроизведения.
Хочется узнать как добавить такой функционал в свое приложение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если кратко, надо предоставить DBus интерфейс согластно этой [спеке](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mpris-spec/).

Comment: да, кстати, из xml файлов спеки должно быть возможно получить код Qt'шного класса, для простого интегрирования, но как именно на память я не скажу...